# No provider for HttpClient even HttpClientModule is already added to app.module.ts

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, angular-httpclient

I am currently studying Angular and ASP.NET Core Web API but I can't resolve the error regarding `HttpClient`.

Main error message:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[EmployeesService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!

I already followed the one and only solution that I can find in the internet which is adding `HttpClient` module in my main `app.module` but it's still not working.

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeesListComponent } from './components/employees/employees-list/employees-list.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeesListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`employees.services.ts`:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.development';
import { Employee } from '../models/employee.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeesService {

  baseApiUrl: string = environment.baseApiUrl;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]>
  {
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this.baseApiUrl + '/api/employees')
  }
}
```

PS: my API is working fine, its just I can't connect it to the Angular front end. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using standalone ?

Comment: Everything looks good. Hypothetically, could be something in Component, but you would probably get a different error message. Do you have a project in Git that I can look?

Comment: what version of Angular are you using? Should work if you use Angular 8 and above. BTW use relative path also for environment

Answer (score -1):

Based on the provided code, it seems that you have correctly imported the HttpClientModule in your AppModule. However, the error message suggests that the HttpClient provider is still not available.

Here are a few suggestions to resolve the issue:

1. Make sure you have saved all your files and restarted the development server. Sometimes changes in the code may not take effect until the server is restarted.
2. Check if you have any other modules in your application that import the HttpClientModule. If so, ensure that those modules are also correctly importing HttpClientModule.
3. Verify that the EmployeesService is correctly added to the providers array in your AppModule. Since you are using the providedIn: 'root' syntax, you don't need to add it to the providers array explicitly. However, double-check to ensure it is not accidentally added multiple times.
4. If you have multiple environments (e.g., environment.development.ts, environment.production.ts), make sure that the correct environment file is being used. Ensure that the environment.baseApiUrl is correctly pointing to your API.
5. If all else fails, try clearing the Angular CLI cache by running the following command in your project's root directory: npm cache clean --force. Then, restart the development server and rebuild your application.

Hopefully, one of these suggestions will help resolve the issue. If the problem persists, please provide any additional error messages or code snippets that may be relevant.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried to turn off my computer and when I came back it is now working. Haha.